# Taping on searchbar causes exception but only on a real device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

taping on my searchbar causes the following exception:`"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath isEqualToString:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d52d9b0'"`

Well doing so using the simulator everything works fine. But on a real device the app crashes.

For debugging I placed a breakpoint on every method in the regarding view controller but no one of my methods is called after taping before the app crashes. 
After that I tried to implement all methods from `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol and from `UISearchDisplayDelegate` protocol. Again I placed a breakpoint and some `NSLog` debug output.
Before the crash only `- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller` is called.

Any idea where to look or what to try? I don't understand why the exception isn't fired on the simulator. I am really wondering whats going on ;)

Here is the code causing with the bug:

```
        NSString *labelText;
if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
    if (self.filteredStrings > 0) {
        labelText = [self.filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
else
{
     ...
}

    cell.textLabel.text = labelText;
```

Ok and here is the fixed code:

```
            NSString *labelText;
if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
    if (self.filteredStrings > 0) {
        labelText = [self.filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = labelText;
    }
}
else
{
     ...
     cell.textLabel.text = labelText;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code? You can always profile your app in the SIM with the zombies instrument. Seems to be something like that.

Comment: Well my code isn`t called at that moment. Profiling in SIM won't help, the problem only exits on real devices. If I am wrong with that feel free to correct me ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant profile using the device and if it's possible to show some of your code here so that we can help you out.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. The only method I didn't break was - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath because there are so many cells. I tried to assign a string that was not initialized to the cells text label. But I'm still wondering why it worked using the simulator.